# Trouble displaying list having table in itemTpl

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

I am having a list which has table in a itemtpl

```
{
                                            xtype: 'list',
                                            deferEmptyText: false,  
                                            height:140,
                                            store:'Store',
                                            scrollable:false,                                                                                           
                                            itemTpl:'<table><tr><td><b>{A}</b></td></tr><tr><td>{B} </td></tr><tr><td>{C}</td><td>{value}</td></tr></table>'
}
```

The data in my store is

```
{ A:'Name1',
  B:'Name2',
  C:'Name3',
  value:0
}
```

I want the data to be displayed as

```
Name1    0 
Name2    0
Name3    0
```

How should I arrange the data in my store so that it can be shown in the above mentioned format.Right now the td tag is not functioning as expected.

Answer (score 0):

At first go [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List) and see how `itemTpl` is used. And regarding your query, you try this snippet:

```
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: '{title} {value}',
                data: [
                {
                    title: 'Name1',
                    value: 0
                },
                {
                    title: 'Name2',
                    value: 0
                },
                {
                    title: 'Name3',
                    value: 0
                },
                {
                    title: 'Name4',
                    value: 0
                }
                ]
            }
```

By this you will get your desired format of data. Here `data` is nothing but the `store`. So in your store data should be like this.